# How to use group by on a DataTable in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have `DataTable` with columns:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
```

I need to select:

```
sum Column1, Count Distinct (Column2), Column3, Column4
```

group by Column3, Column4

I am using this code but with wrong result in count distinct

```
var queryDGroup = dtsecscaleditemsCloned2.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["Column3"], Col2 = r["Column4"]});

foreach (var g in queryDGroup)
{
    DataRow addedRow = dtsecscaleditemsCloned.Rows.Add();
    addedRow["Column1"] = g.Distinct ().Count();
    addedRow["Column4"] = g.Key.Col2;
    addedRow["Column3"] = g.Key.Col1;
    addedRow["store_Code"] = "";
    addedRow["Column2"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Column2"));
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `Count (Distinct Column2)`, not `Count Distinct (Column2)`. There is a difference.

Comment: What is `dtsecscaleditemsCloned2` and what is the indexer return on each instance in that type. Show the relevant code for the type(s).

Comment: @Igor dtsecscaleditemsCloned2  is the Datatable which i query in it

Comment: Try : List<DataRow> queryDGroup = dtsecscaleditemsCloned2.AsEnumerable()
               .GroupBy(r => new object[] {r.Field<string>("Column3"), r.Field<string>("Column4")});

Comment: Try g.Select(r => r.Field<int>("Column2)).Distinct().Count();

Comment: What is Column3 & Column4 types?

Comment: Why don't you perform the correct query before it gets loaded into a DataTable? Why are you using a DataTable at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could understand, you're trying to count the distinct values in the `Column2` column. You need to project to that column first before doing anything else. Otherwise you're just counting distinct `DataRow` instances (which will have no meaning here).

I'd write it like this:

```
var query =
    from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
    group new
    {
        Column1 = r.Field<int>("Column1"),
        Column2 = r.Field<int>("Column2"),
    }
    by new
    {
        Column3 = r.Field<string>("Column3"),
        Column4 = r.Field<string>("Column4"),
    }
    into g
    select new
    {
        Column1 = g.Select(x => x.Column1).Distinct().Count(), // project first
        Column2 = g.Sum(x => x.Column2),
        g.Key.Column3,
        g.Key.Column4,
        StoreCode = "",
    };
```

Comment: I never use query syntax, but it seems query syntax is _beautifuler_ than extension method syntax for doing the group by. I think it is because of the way you've written it out. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var queryDGroup = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(c => new { Col3 = c["Column3"], Col4 = c["Column4"] },
             x => x,
            (k, g) => new
            {
                 Col1Sum = g.Sum(t => t.Field<int>("Column1")),
                 Col2Count = g.Select(t => t.Field<int>("Column2")).Distinct().Count()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

The object `queryDGroup` is an anonymously typed object with two properties: `Col1Sum` and `Col1Count` (the names are self-explanatory).

You can either create strongly typed anonymous objects as you select elements while doing group by (the second parameter to the `GroupBy`), or cast to individual column's datatypes in the result selector part (the last parameter to the `GroupBy`), as I have shown here.